# How to get JavaScript to ensure no fields are null

Tags: javascript, html

Quite a simple one, I'm sure... as you may be able to tell, quite new to this!

I need a JavaScript code to ensure that no fields in a form are null, including text, number, email, tel...
If there is one field that happens to be null, it should submit an alert. 
If all fields do have some data in them, it should submit an alert that confirms everything is good.

Can anyone help? Please? :D

My codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Billma Tours - Bookings</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> Billma Tours </h1>

  <ul id="menubar">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="customerbooking.html">Bookings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <br>

  <h2> Booking Management </h2>

  <div id="pagebrief">
    <p> Welcome to our booking page. If you wish to make a booking, please fill out the form below and submit your request. </p>
    <p> Please ensure that all fields are filled in. For reference, the information table is below. </p>
  </div>

  <br>

  <table>
    <tr id="tabletop">
      <td> Name of Tour Package </td>
      <td> Locations Included</td>
      <td> Cost Per Person </td>
      <td> Tour Guide </td>
      <td> Next Available Date </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Dine and Dusted </td>
      <td> Restaurants/Food retailers on central Wellington streets </td>
      <td> NZ$ 60.00 </td>
      <td> James Sanderson </td>
      <td> Monday, June 8, 2020 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> A View to a Thrill</td>
      <td> Wellington Cable Car, Brooklyn Wind Turbine, Mount Victoria </td>
      <td> NZ$ 130.50 </td>
      <td> Bill Colenso </td>
      <td> Thursday, June 11, 2020 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Movie-ing On </td>
      <td> Weta Workshop, Park Road Post Production </td>
      <td> NZ$ 117.75 </td>
      <td> Xiulan Ma </td>
      <td> Wednesday, June 10, 2020 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Water Sight to Behold </td>
      <td> Te Papa, New Zealand Parliament, Botanical Gardens </td>
      <td> NZ$ 150.00 </td>
      <td> James Sanderson </td>
      <td> Saturday, June 13, 2020 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br>

  <div id="bookingform">
    <h4> Personal Details </h4>

    <p><span> First and Last Name: </span></p>
    <form name="confirm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name">

      <p><span> Phone Number: </span></p>

      <input type="tel" name="phone">

      <p><span> Email Address: </span></p>

      <input type="email" name="emailaddress">


      <br>

      <h4> Tour Information</h4>

      <p><span> Tour package: </span></p>

      <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="Dine and Dusted"> Dine and Dusted <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="A View to a Thrill"> A View to a Thrill <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="Movie-ing On"> Movie-ing On <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="Water Sight to Behold"> Water Sight to Behold <br>


      <p><span> Amount of people attending: </span></p>

      <select name="no.pplattending">
        <option value="blank"> Please select an option </option>
        <option value="1"> 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
        <option value="6"> 6 </option>
        <option value="7"> 7 </option>
        <option value="8"> 8 </option>
        <option value="9"> 9 </option>
        <option value="10+"> 10+ </option>
      </select>


      <p><span> Date of Tour: </span></p>

      <input type="date" name="tourdate"><br>


      <h4> Payment Details </h4>

      <p><span> Name on Card: </span></p>

      <input type="text" name="cardname">


      <p><span> Card Number: </span></p>

      <input type="number" name="cardnumber">


      <p><span> Card Expiry: </span></p>

      <input type="number" name="cardexpmonth">
      <input type="number" name="cardexpyear">


      <p><span> Card Security Code: </span></p>

      <input type="number" name="cardsecurity">

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

    <br>



  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is "myscripts.js"?

Comment: do you mean null or blank? 
`document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el=>!el.value&&alert(el.name+' is null'))`?  This looks like a homework assignment.  I saw the exact same thing in another post referencing homework due today.  But she at least posted some code attempt.

Comment: Ah yes, I mean blank. Will update post to include JS so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, you need set blank value in select as empty

`<option value=""> Please select an option </option>`

And handle logic to check if radio is check or not as

```
if (x[i].type == 'radio') {
  var checked = [...document.getElementsByName('Tour package')].find(c => c['checked']);
  if (checked == undefined) {
     valid = false;
     break;
  }
}
```

And use for loop to check form controls as below

```js
  function validateForm() {

            var x = document.forms["confirm"];
            var valid = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i].type == 'radio') {

                    var checked = [...document.getElementsByName('Tour package')].find(c => c['checked']);
                    if (checked == undefined) {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (x[i].value == null || x[i].value == '') {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!valid) {
                alert("Please fill in all available fields.")
            } else {
                alert('Form is valid');
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Billma Tours - Bookings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1> Billma Tours </h1>

    <ul id="menubar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="customerbooking.html">Bookings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <br>

    <h2> Booking Management </h2>

    <div id="pagebrief">
        <p> Welcome to our booking page. If you wish to make a booking, please fill out the form below and submit your
            request. </p>
        <p> Please ensure that all fields are filled in. For reference, the information table is below. </p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <table>
        <tr id="tabletop">
            <td> Name of Tour Package </td>
            <td> Locations Included</td>
            <td> Cost Per Person </td>
            <td> Tour Guide </td>
            <td> Next Available Date </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Dine and Dusted </td>
            <td> Restaurants/Food retailers on central Wellington streets </td>
            <td> NZ$ 60.00 </td>
            <td> James Sanderson </td>
            <td> Monday, June 8, 2020 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A View to a Thrill</td>
            <td> Wellington Cable Car, Brooklyn Wind Turbine, Mount Victoria </td>
            <td> NZ$ 130.50 </td>
            <td> Bill Colenso </td>
            <td> Thursday, June 11, 2020 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Movie-ing On </td>
            <td> Weta Workshop, Park Road Post Production </td>
            <td> NZ$ 117.75 </td>
            <td> Xiulan Ma </td>
            <td> Wednesday, June 10, 2020 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Water Sight to Behold </td>
            <td> Te Papa, New Zealand Parliament, Botanical Gardens </td>
            <td> NZ$ 150.00 </td>
            <td> James Sanderson </td>
            <td> Saturday, June 13, 2020 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>

    <div id="bookingform">
        <h4> Personal Details </h4>

        <p><span> First and Last Name: </span></p>
        <form name="confirm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name">

            <p><span> Phone Number: </span></p>

            <input type="tel" name="phone">

            <p><span> Email Address: </span></p>

            <input type="email" name="emailaddress">


            <br>

            <h4> Tour Information</h4>

            <p><span> Tour package: </span></p>

            <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="Dine and Dusted"> Dine and Dusted <br>
            <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="A View to a Thrill"> A View to a Thrill <br>
            <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="Movie-ing On"> Movie-ing On <br>
            <input type="radio" name="Tour package" value="Water Sight to Behold"> Water Sight to Behold <br>


            <p><span> Amount of people attending: </span></p>

            <select name="no.pplattending">
                <option value=""> Please select an option </option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                <option value="10+"> 10+ </option>
            </select>


            <p><span> Date of Tour: </span></p>

            <input type="date" name="tourdate"><br>


            <h4> Payment Details </h4>

            <p><span> Name on Card: </span></p>

            <input type="text" name="cardname">


            <p><span> Card Number: </span></p>

            <input type="number" name="cardnumber">


            <p><span> Card Expiry: </span></p>

            <input type="number" name="cardexpmonth">
            <input type="number" name="cardexpyear">

            <p><span> Card Security Code: </span></p>

            <input type="number" name="cardsecurity">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

        <br>



    </div>
    <script>
      
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `return false;` like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["confirm"]["code"].value;

    if (x == null) {
        alert("Please fill in all available fields.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

(And you forgot a semicolon after the alert function)

Maybe the HTML5 form validation would be interesting too:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp